Cannot install postgres on Centos 7 as signature cannot be verified/gpg keys not imported
I am currently trying to access a postgres 12 RDS on a private VPC through an EC2 instance on the same VPC, and in order to do so I am trying to install postgres on this instance (which is a Centos 7 AlmaLinux instance). After the initial attempt, I read that there are EOL and depreciation issues related to postgres 12 on Centos 7, so I followed the guide related to installing older versions of postgres on Centos 7 from here: https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages/#pgredhatoldrepos
With the code:
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-12.repo
[pgdg12-archive]
name=PostgreSQL 12 RPMs for RHEL/CentOS 7
baseurl=https://yum-archive.postgresql.org/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.postgresql.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG
EOF'

However I still get this error when running sudo yum install postgresql12-server:
Repository pgdg12 is listed more than once in the configuration

https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/common/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:        

[Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for pgdg-common`

and
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: 

[Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for pgdg12

Should I attempt removing the existing repos in yum.repos.d or would that not even help?
Thank you in advance.

What is in /etc/yum.repos.d/? Could there be two files there that have pgdg12 in them? Check with grep -Hn 'pgdg12' /etc/yum.repos.d/* If you get more than 1 file listed, you have your answer. Also check the content of /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-12.repo (you can just cat /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-12.repo). Verify they are what they should be.

In the results I have both:
/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo:80:[pgdg12]
and
/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg.repo:1:[pgdg12]
and
/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-12.repo:1:[pgdg12-archive]
with some files in-between that include pgdg12-source/debuginfo/etc. Should I just remove all the pgdg repositories and restart from scratch?

Yes, just pick one and move it somewhere, e.g. mkdir -p "$HOME/tmp" (which will create a tmp directory in your user directory , e.g. /home/youruser/tmp) and then move one of the files (like /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo) to that tmp directory with  mv /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo $HOME/tmp. That way you can simply move that file back if you need it. Easy way to avoid ever deleting something you might need later. You will need root (or sudo, etc.)  to accomplish the move. Try the install. If you needed that repo, just move it back and move the other to tmp.

Also note, this question is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites Super User or Unix & Linux since it isn't directly "programming" related. I'd start with Unix & Linux. If you don't get an answer here (or you start getting dunned with downvotes or closevotes), just move the question to that site and include the info about the two repo files with [pgdg12]. I think this will solve it for you, but if it doesn't, then that StackExchange site will provide much more help.

And ... good job on the formatting of your question.

Thank you for the input! So far I am still getting a 403 error because of the link, so no luck at the moment and I am looking into alternatives. Before I migrate this question to another StackExchange site, regardless of what I try to install (whether it is dnf or anything unrelated to postgres), I keep getting a 'https://yum-archive.postgresql.org/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden' error even though I am not trying to install it...any idea why this might be happening? Sorry I am a bit new to unix.

The RHEL repo may or may not be public -- I don't know. I'd move the pgdg.repo file back to /etc/yum from your tmp and move /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo into tmp and try again. Old versions can be a challenge and a pain. If that fails -- time to migrate -- I'm out of ammo. I don't have Centos, RH or postgresql-12. Bloody Arch is already at postgresql 16.3.
